# How do I loop over output from shuf?

Tags: bash, shell-script

If I do `gshuf -e $(seq 1 10)` in bash it will print the numbers 1 thru 10 in random order.

But if I do:

```
a=$(shuf -e $(seq 1 10))
for i in "${a[@]}"
do
    echo $i
    echo "next"
done
```

It prints all ten numbers followed by "next".

How do I loop over the output from shuf (or gshuf in os x)? The variable, `a`,  seems to be a string, so I could split it. But that seems sort of sloppy. How do I get shuf to output an array?

Comment: Is the output of `gshuf` on a single line, or multiple lines?

Comment: Just use `for i in $a`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using a scalar assignment. Either use an array

```
a=( $(shuf -e $(seq 1 10)) )
for i in "${a[@]}"
do
    echo $i
    echo "next"
done
```

or let the shell split the scalar

```
a=$(shuf -e $(seq 1 10))
for i in ${a}
do
    echo $i
    echo "next"
done
```

Comment: Either way, that assumes you've not modified `$IFS`, that is, that it still contains the newline character and doesn't contain decimal digits.

Comment: Stephane, in the first place I assume that the context is as shown. If there's critical code around the sample code the poster will certainly file a new question with appropriate new context.

Comment: I'm just point out. The split+glob operator behaviour depends on the content of that variable, so it's worth point it out when recommending its usage for anyone stumbling on the answer.

Comment: @Janis did not realize that scalar and array assignments had different syntax in bash. thanks a lot

Answer (score 8):

you don't need to store the output in a variable:

```
seq 10 | shuf | while read i; do echo $i; done
```

That runs the while loop in a subshell, so the `i` variable cannot persist into the current shell. You can `shopt -s lastpipe` to counter that, or avoid piping altogether

```
while read i; do echo $i; done < <( shuf -e $(seq 10) )
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to process `$a` as an array you need to initialise it as an array:

```
a=( $(shuf -e $(seq 1 10)) )
```

Then your loop produces the expected output.

Comment: On one hand, this works fine for the use case present. On the other hand, it doesn't work in many other use cases -- has all the same bugs as `foo=( $bar )`; undesired glob expansion, unexpected string-splitting behavior, etc. Much better to use `readarray -t a < <(seq 1 10 | shuf)` or `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a a < <(seq 1 10 | shuf)` or `a=( ); while read -r; do a+=( "$REPLY" ); done < <(seq 1 10 | shuf)` if one wants to write code that'll do the normal/expected thing with more antagonistic inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Just loop over output of `shuf`, you don't need variable here:

```
for i in $(shuf -e {1..10}); do
  echo "$i"
  echo "next"
done
```

Comment: Well unless $a has re-use later :) In which case `for i in $a` would suffice

Answer (score 1):

a one-liner...

```
shuf -e {1..10} | xargs -I%    echo % next
```

Comment: I see three commands: `shuf`, `xargs` and `echo`

Comment: @anthon, I meant "loop over the output from shuf" and execute just one command. Probably I should rephrase it (my English is awful).

Comment: I would call it a one-liner. But if it solves the problem the name, nor the number of commands is important.